# How to cast Date with Time Zone into DateTime SQL Server

Tags: sql, datetime, casting

i'm trying to cast a datetime with Time Zone, the original date is like:
07/06/2015 08:35:02 AM PDT

So i want to have the MAX date of the column (UserAddDate),

i'm using this formula in SQL Server:

MAX(CAST(LEFT(SIG.UserAddDate, 10) AS nvarchar))

and it works, i got this:
02/18/2016, but i don't want to cast this into nvarchar, i want to cast it into DATETIME,
And when I try to cast it, i got this error:
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Anyone knows why? , Thank you.

Comment: Does you SQL Server version support Standard SQL's `CAST(MAX(SIG.UserAddDate) AS DATE)`?

Comment: The server might be interpreting your date as "day 2 of month 18" or "day 18 of month 2". And since month 18 is invalid you get na error. The ideal situation is never to deal with "date strings" in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use CAST. This should be compatible with AM, PM:

```
 CREATE TABLE #SIG (UserAddDate varchar(100)) --temp table
 INSERT INTO #SIG VALUES ('07/06/2015 08:35:02 AM PDT')
                        ,('07/06/2015 10:35:02 AM PDT')
                        ,('07/06/2015 02:35:02 PM PDT') --hour is lesser but is PM time   

 SELECT MAX( CAST(LEFT(#SIG.UserAddDate, 22) as datetime) ) AS MaxDateTime
   FROM #SIG

 --DROP TABLE #SIG
```

Would produce:

```
MaxDateTime
2015-07-06 14:35:02.000
```